# Node Async with functions

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm trying to use Async module with 2 functions, here is the code. There's something wrong, the  *console.dir* are working, but the last one in *function(err, results)* doesn't work. Can any one help me?

The last step that I want to do is render the *oftArrayFullInfo* and *oftNextInfo*

```
async.parallel({
        one: function(callback){
            auxFunctions.foofunc1(foo1, foo1, function(oftArrayFullInfo){
                console.log("****** ASYNC 1 ARRAY");
                console.dir(oftArrayFullInfo);
                callback(oftArrayFullInfo);
            });
        },
        two: function(callback){
            auxFunctions.foofunc2(foo1, foo1, function(oftNextInfo){
                console.log("****** ASYNC 2 ARRAY");
                console.dir(oftNextInfo);
                callback(oftNextInfo);
            });
        }
    },
    function(err, results){
        console.log("****** RENDER 1");
        console.dir(results.one);
        console.log("****** RENDER 2")
        console.dir(results.two);
        //res.render('myView', {title: 'Job Info', oftArrayFullInfo}, {title: 'Next Jobs Info', oftNextInfo});
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're not calling the callbacks correctly.

`async` callbacks, and asynchronous callbacks in Node.js in general, take two arguments: the first one is used to pass any errors (or `null` if there aren't any), the second one is used to pass the result.

You are calling them with only the first argument:

```
callback(oftArrayFullInfo);
```

This will make `async` think that the function has failed, which will cause `results` in the final callback to be undefined. When you subsequently try to access `results.one`, an error will be thrown.

To fix this, you should call the callbacks properly:

```
callback(null, oftArrayFullInfo)
callback(null, oftNextInfo)
```

And, as suggested already, you should uncomment the `res.render()`.

Eventually, you should also make your auxilliary functions (`auxFunctions.foofunc1` and `auxFunctions.foofunc2`) adhere to the same calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

ok you did everything right except when u send data from re.render() to your templates you have to send in key,value pairs.so intead

```
res.render('myView', {title: 'Job Info', oftArrayFullInfo}, {title: 'Next Jobs Info', oftNextInfo});
```

you should use

```
res.render('myView', {title: 'Job Info', arrayFullInfo : oftArrayFullInfo}, {title: 'Next Jobs Info', nextInfo : oftNextInfo});
```

now you can access these values with the key names  arrayFullInfo and nextInfo in your template